# FInd the largest square in a histogram

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have been given an array of integers like,

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 8, 4, 5, 6]
a[i] -> Height of each bar in the histogram
0 < len(a) < 100
0 <= a[i] < 100
```

My task is to find the edge length of the largest square I can find in this histogram.

Output for the above input is,

```
4
```

**Explanation**

[image: Explanation]

I wrote the below code for the solution, but it is giving me wrong answer. I am unable to find any related article on the problem.

```
def findMaxSquare(arr):
    cur = 0
    for i in range(n-1):
        min_height = arr[i]
        length = 1
        if min_height > 0:
            cur = max(cur, 1)
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            min_height = min(min_height, arr[j])
            length += 1
            if min_height < length:
                break
            cur = max(cur, min(min_height, length))
    return cur
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is exactly similar to the Maximum rectangular area of a Histogram. Here, the idea for brute force is:

For current bar height, try to maximum expand on the Left side as well as Right side along with keeping track of the largest height of the left or right of the current bar. While we are doing that, we need to take the minimum of calculated expanded width and height of the current bar to mark the edge length of the maximum area square for the current bar.
The algorithm runs in O(n^2) and O(n) space.

Following is the optimized version (similar to the maximum rectangular area of Histogram) with Time complexity of O(n) and Space of O(n) in the worst case:

```
    public int maxSquareAreaHistogram(int[] heights) {
        Deque<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<>();
        int i=0, maxArea = 0;

        while (i < heights.length) {
            // Stack keeps track of last largest height. As soon as we
            // encounter a height which is less than the previous height,
            // we need to find the maximum area for the bar at the top of stack as
            // the area cannot be extended to the right. 
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && heights[i] < heights[stack.peek()]) {
                int idx = stack.pop();
                int width = stack.isEmpty() ? i : i - stack.peek() - 1;
                int edge = Math.min(width, heights[idx]);
                maxArea = Math.max(maxArea, edge * edge);
            }

            stack.push(i++);
        }

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            int idx = stack.pop();
            int width = stack.isEmpty() ? i : i - stack.peek() - 1;
            int edge = Math.min(width, heights[idx]);
            maxArea = Math.max(maxArea, edge * edge);
        }

        return maxArea;
    }
```

PS: The code is written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a solution where you

- first identify all possible rectangles (for each bar, search to the left and to the right for other bars that have at least same height)
- then, for each rectangle, check what's smaller.. width or height. and with the smaller size, build up the square
- finally check which is the biggest square

In the sample given by you, both bar-5 and bar-7 would return a rectangle with height 4 and a width of 6... so you should have 2 rectangles and both resolve to a 4x4 square.

Comment: as it sounds like a homework, I expect you think about the code yourself. With the textual description of the algorithm, it should already be easy to implement the code yourself.